# fix app for only portrait mode or landscape

Tags: ios, swift

I want to disable the landscape/portrait orientation for my new iOS quiz app. in android it is very simple and I know how to do it but I am not able to find the suitable file in iOS from where I can stop the app orientation. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this section in General tab:

[image]

you can set the `Device Orientation` by selecting the check boxes.